# When does a HashTable / Python dict stop probing?

Tags: python, java, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable

In Java I'm building a datastructure that is supposed to resemble dictionaries in Python.
(As far as I understand this is called a "HashTable" in java context.)

I have read [the following Python documentation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c#l33) in order to arrive at the probing function (as I wished to prevent using linear probing)

Now I have come to a point where Im trying to retrieve an element from my "dict" that doesn't exist in its internal array. It seems that my probing function will go in circles endlessly searching for the non-existent element, and i therefor wish to break and return null at some point.

When should I stop probing and return null?

My current solution is to count every probe. Once `probeCount > size` I `break`.
This however, seems like a poor solution as the time complexity to determine that an element is not present would be O(n), n being size of my array.

The following in my probing code:

```java
public Object get(long id) {

        int count = 0;

        int hashedIndex = (int) id;
        if (hashedIndex < 0) hashedIndex = -hashedIndex;
        hashedIndex = hashedIndex % size;
        int perturb = hashedIndex;
        while(true) {
            if (nodes[hashedIndex] != null || count > size) {
                if (count > size) {
                    System.out.println("null");
                    break;
                }
                if (nodes[hashedIndex].identifier == id) {
                    break;
                }
            }                       
            hashedIndex = (5*hashedIndex + 1 + perturb) % size;
            perturb >>= 5;
            count++;
        }
        return nodes[hashedIndex];
}
```

Comment: You will need some sort of search tree. Why don't you use a HashMap directly?

Comment: HashMaps do not support primitive types or single objects, searchable by a field. And memory-usage is a bit of an issue for me.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "single objects," but if you want collection support for primitive objects, consider a preexisting library like [fastutil](https://fastutil.di.unimi.it/#core).

Comment: Single object as in: HashMap<MyObject>, where the key to the object is a field in the object.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, just curious, will fastutil work with streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Python dict stops probing once it finds an empty, non-"dummy" slot - one that is not holding a key, and is not holding a "dummy" marker that indicates a key was deleted there.

The dict implementation ensures that at least one such slot always exists (and usually many more), and the probe sequence is guaranteed to check all slots eventually, so this guarantees termination.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I don't know how I could overlook this. So if I understand correctly:
If the value had already been added previously, we would never hit a "dummy-slot" while doing a lookup. And if it hadn't been added before we might instantly hit one, or might after some amount of probes.

Comment: @MarkusB: The search can find a dummy marker even if it's searching for a key that exists. That just means that something used to be in that slot. The search only stops once it finds an empty, *non*-dummy slot.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Do you know whether it's still only O(n) like in Python? In Python it's easy to cause linear search time by using keys with equal hash values, but with Java's `long` I don't know.

Comment: Ah, wait, they're actually hashing the `long` to `int`, so it's easy to cause linear time searches here as well.

Comment: @KellyBundy Well hopefully the long to int conversion along with the pseudo random probing should cause the values to spread out evenly, preventing linear time and achieving O(1) average.